# drupal subscribe or buy in paypal first and then become a member in the site kind of module!

Tags: drupal, paypal, payment-gateway, ubercart

My client has a requirement which I am not able to understand as to how to fulfill it. He has a page where there are two subscriptions and one buy now product. Out of two subscriptions one is recurring and other one is not. He wants the users to pay first and then automatically become member of the site. How is that possible? Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable behavior on specific actions using drupal commerce: drupal.org/project/commerce
Then extend that with the role subscription module that enables you to grant roles on behaviors like checkout: http://drupal.org/project/role_subscription
For the reoccurring payments I would use the commerce subscription module on top of the other two: http://drupal.org/project/commerce_subscription

E-commerce can be a bit tricky to set up so also check out the documentation on drupalcommerce.org/ and the project pages I listed above.